# angular 6 Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet Error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to redirect the user to a custom error page when a subscribe call to an observable throws an error.
router.navigateByUrl('errorpage')
I am getting the below error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a little more info?
like what are your routes like.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@ViewChild(RouterOutlet) outlet: RouterOutlet;

constructor(
    private router: Router
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
        if (e instanceof ActivationStart && e.snapshot.outlet === "errorpage")
            this.outlet.deactivate();
    });
}
```

Refrence:https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/20712